# Web Part Permissions

Tags: 2007

I have main site and a subsite. I installed custom web part in bin and added Safe option to the web config. It works fine on main site but when I go via subsite - I get 403 error. Note - the subsite uses Forms auth. Main site (where it works) uses windows auth.

Any ideas how to solve tihs one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the dll to GAC and make sure you add it to the safecontrols.

Answer (score 2):

From what you are saying about your authentication setup (main site => windows, subsite => forms) it sounds like the two sites are located in separate web applications.

If that is the case, you will need to copy the web part assembly to the /bin folder of the second web application and make the web.config changes there too.

Comment: Well, adding to both bin folders didn't help.

Adding to GAC helped though, but I'm still wandering why it's not working out of the bin.

I did have entry in web.config for SafeControls.

Comment: Its probably to do with code access security. dlls in the GAC have full trust,but assemblies in the /bin either require a trust setting inthe web.config or a custom cas policy.